# Angular2: loop typescript dictionary in html component

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

I'm developing an Angular 2 application and I want to loop a Typescript dictionary to show its data.

The interface I want to show is:

```
export interface IProductionOrderDetail {
    productionOrderName: string;
    productCode: string;
    batches: IBatch[];
    levels: IAggLevel[];
    variableData: IVarData[];
    codeStatistics: ICodeStatistics;
}

export interface ICodeStatistics {
    [index: number]: {
        commissionedCodes: number;
        decommissionedCodes: number;
        aggregatedCodes: number;
    }
}
```

I know that I can do this in TypeScript to loop the dictionary:

```
for (let key in myDictionary) {
    let value = myDictionary[key];
    // Use `key` and `value`
}
```

So, I have decided to use it in the same way in a html component:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let key in prodetail.codeStatistics">
    <div class="col-md-1">{{queryLevelName(key)}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{prodetail.codeStatistics[key].commissionedCodes}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{prodetail.codeStatistics[key].decommissionedCodes}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{prodetail.codeStatistics[key].aggregatedCodes}}</div>
</div>
```

But it seems that there is something wrong with the `in` in `*ngFor="let key in prodetail.codeStatistics"` because I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
>   ]*ngFor="let key in
>   prodetail.codeStatistics">

How can I loop over the dictionary?a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In latest version of Angular (6.0.0+) : So great to find the best solution from Angular itself provides pipe to loop through JSON , and its `keyvalue`**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of jsonObj | keyvalue'>
   Key: {{item.key}}

    <div *ngFor='let obj of item.value'>
        {{ obj.title }}
        {{ obj.desc }}
    </div>

</div>
```

**[WORKIGN DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-loop-pipe)**

---

**Previously :**

**As angular doesn't support jsonObject looping from template side and there is no ngForIn directive yet ,**

**You can loop through the data only if its array with *ngForOf , but if you want to loop through json or dictionary You can do it like**

> Component side :

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

> Template side :

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(prodetail.codeStatistics)">
    <div class="col-md-1">{{queryLevelName(key)}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{prodetail.codeStatistics[key].commissionedCodes}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{prodetail.codeStatistics[key].decommissionedCodes}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{prodetail.codeStatistics[key].aggregatedCodes}}</div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-loop-pipe)**